# What is the purpose of 2 fully connected hidden layers in VGG16?

Tags: conv-neural-network, computer-vision, transfer-learning

Here is the architecture of VGG16:
[image]

The first 18 convolution layers can be understood as feature extraction. How about the two fully connect hidden layers after them? What is their purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've extracted the features from an image, using all those convolutional layers, you need to link the features to the output/target. This is what the final layers do.

In simpler neural networks, you might have to provide already identified features as inputs, and so you would only have these final few layers.

Comment: So when I fine tune VGG16 for a new task, I have to remove these 2 hidden layers and add my own for training. Is this correct?